# Unable to display one post in Mailchimp campaign

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to display just one post or just the most recent post only in a mailchimp campaign. I've tried using feedblocks but it doesn't display anything.
Below is the code I am using (I checked to make sure my rss feed is working)

```
    *|FEEDBLOCK:http://website.com/feed/|* 
   <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=5]|* 
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center"><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</a></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">*|FEEDITEM:DATE|*</td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT_FULL|*</td> 
         </tr>
       *|END:FEEDITEMS|*
   </table>
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the default RSSITEMS code provided by Mailchimp. If you delete *|RSSITEMS|* at the beginning of the code block it only displays one post.